# How to click option in dropdown menu which does not have "select" tag using Selenium Python?

Tags: python, html, selenium, drop-down-menu

The html code of the dropdown I am concerned with
[image]]

Here's link to the "Helfulness" dropdown I am talking about.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.delta.mobile.android&hl=en

After I visit the pagethrough selenium I want to automate the process of selecting the 1st dropdown list and choose option "Newest". The problem is the dropdown menu does not have the select tag.Can anyone help ?

Comment: I dont see any dropdown in the above link

Answer (score 0):

Try using Selenium IDE to get the name, the id or the xpath of the dropdown menu.

Answer (score 0):

## 1. Selenium

You can use XPath to find that button by its text:

```py
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[./text() = 'Helpfulness']")
button.click()
```

## 2. Using Capybara (which uses Selenium)

More generally (and reliably), you can use [capybara-py](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/capybara-py) to click all kinds of buttons (not just `<button>` elements):

```py
page.click_button("Helpfulness")
```

It also properly escapes your search string and retries if the button is not yet interactable.

Answer (score 0):

When we want to select the value from the dropdown which doesn't have select tag , we have build the logic to select it.First step would be clicking on the dropdown and then finding a generic locator for the values of the dropdown. Locator should be completely dependent on the value of the dropdown so that just by adding the required value we should be able to get the unique locator , like below

```
public void selectValueFromDropDown(WebDriver driver,String value) throws InterruptedException{
        //click on the dropdown
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='dropdown-menu'][1]")).click();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        // select value from dropdown
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='dropdown-menu-children']//li//button[text()='"+value+"']")).click();
    }
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Did it help you?

Answer (score 0):

Hey I have locate this by following code:

1.WebElement arrow=driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//i[@class='google-material-icons VfPpkd-kBDsod W7A5Qb' and @aria-hidden='true'])[4]"));
**//**here I have locate developer contact dropdown****
2.arrow.click(); **//**clicked on it****
3.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='http://www.delta.com/app']")).click();;
}
**//**located first website from dropdown list using xpath ****

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).